# .htaccess RewriteRule required

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on WordPress and I have the following URL which is working fine:

```
http://example.com/afm/forum/forums/forum/customer-forum/
```

But I want if a user enters the following URL they shouldn't be redirected by the first one:

```
http://example.com/project/forum/customer-forum/
```

Also, all inner pages should work on `http://example.com/project/forum/customer-forum/`

I tried the following in htaccess but it is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^forums/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301, NC, L]
```

Comment: So the URLs `/project/forum/customer-forum/` are outside of WordPress?

Comment: forum is the wordpress folder name, and I am using bbpress forum and bbpress generating the link forums/forum/customer-forum/ but I want customer-forum

Answer (score 0):

> But I want if a user enters the following URL they shouldn't be redirected by the first one:
>   `http://example.com/project/forum/customer-forum/`

To exclude this URL from being processed by WordPress then in the .htaccess file at `/project/forum/customer-forum/.htaccess` you can simply enable the `RewriteEngine`. This will prevent the mod_rewrite directives in the parent (WordPress) .htaccess file from being processed.

```
RewriteEngine On
```